# Javascript canvas width is too large to render

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas that's supposed to render timeline similar to example here:
http://vorg.github.io/timeline.js/examples/cssAnimation.html

However the problem is as I start to zoom in and change timeline scaling the canvas fails to render.

Example of my canvas is here

```
<canvas
 id="timeline"
 width={30 * (zoom * 60)}
 height={400}
></canvas>
```

`Zoom` is basically a input range between 1 and 50 that should allow increasing/decreasing the distance (in pixels) between timeline seconds.

Here is my function to render timeline

```
const drawTimeline = () => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("timeline");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const distanceBetweenLines = (zoom * 60) / 10;
    let currentPosition = 10;
    let lineNumber = 0;

    while (currentPosition < 30 * (zoom * 60) + 15) {
      if (lineNumber % 10 === 0 || lineNumber === 0) {
        ctx.fillText(lineNumber / 10, currentPosition - 3, 15);
        ctx.moveTo(currentPosition, 20);
      } else {
        ctx.moveTo(currentPosition, 25);

        if (zoom >= 5)
          ctx.fillText(`${lineNumber}00`, currentPosition - 5, 20);
      }

      ctx.lineTo(currentPosition, 30);
      ctx.stroke();

      currentPosition += distanceBetweenLines;
      lineNumber++;
    }
}
```

However, at around zoom 37 it no longer renders due to the width being to large. Is there any solution to this? I was trying to find something, but all examples seems to be very outdated.

Comment: try zoom with css transform:scale(n), not with width

Comment: I would highly appreciate any example of how this can be achieved.